# How to Encrypt JwtSecurityToken

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I want to generate a Jwt Token, and then later validate it.

Create token:

```
 var user = await this._applicationUserProvider.GetCurrentUserAsync();

        var claims = new[]
                                {
                    new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, user.UserName),
                    new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.NameId, user.Id),
                    new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
                    };

        var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_appSettings.Token.Key));
        var creds = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

        var token = new JwtSecurityToken(this._appSettings.Token.Issuer,
          this._appSettings.Token.Issuer,
          claims,
          expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(this._appSettings.Token.DownloadTokenExpireMin),
          signingCredentials: creds);
```

Later, I then want to validate this token:

```
 var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_appSettings.Token.Key));

        TokenValidationParameters validationParameters =
                new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidIssuer = this._appSettings.Token.Issuer,
                    ValidAudiences = new[] { this._appSettings.Token.Issuer },
                    IssuerSigningKeys = new[] { key }
                };

        // Now validate the token. If the token is not valid for any reason, an exception will be thrown by the method
        SecurityToken validatedToken;
        JwtSecurityTokenHandler handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var user = handler.ValidateToken(token, validationParameters, out validatedToken);
```

This is throwing an error: Jwt is not well formed.

In searching on this, I found this: https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/1332 which basically says that the Jwt is not encrypted.

However, I have not been able to figure out how to encrypt the token after signing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateToken()` expects token string in compact serialization format. So after building an instance of `JwtSecurityToken`, you should serialize it into JWT in compact format.

You could do it with `JwtSecurityTokenHandler.WriteToken()` call:

```
var token = new JwtSecurityToken(this._appSettings.Token.Issuer,
  this._appSettings.Token.Issuer,
  claims,
  expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(this._appSettings.Token.DownloadTokenExpireMin),
  signingCredentials: creds);

var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
string tokenSerialized = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
```

As result you get a string like

> eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJTb21lIFVzZXIiLCJuYW1laWQiOiIxMjMiLCJqdGkiOiIzMTQ3YWJmOC05MWYzLTRhZmItYjYyYi03MzZlZDJhNTg3ZjQiLCJleHAiOjE1MjI4MjUwNTYsImlzcyI6IlNvbWUgSXNzdWVyIiwiYXVkIjoiU29tZSBJc3N1ZXIifQ.RD0NntbPWBZUyyayB6SRmNzBPuZ86c30btLbSmhPUmo

that could be successfully validated by `JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateToken()`.

Comment: Thank you so much, I will try this shortly.

Comment: This is not encrypted. Base64 decoding the payload of that token reveals an unencrypted object

Comment: Indeed it's not encrypted but it is signed.

Comment: What happens if someone steals the token? He/She can use it to for anything until it expires, correct? Is there a way to secure this behavior? For example, I don't care what is there in that token, I just want it to secure APIs, Is it possible to receive encrypted token from the server that is not decodable? 
I'm using Angular with Dotnet Core 2.1

Answer (score 0):

ChiragMS -

I am dealing with the same issue of encrypting/decrypting the jwt token.  From my research, this can be achieved using the Authnetication Events.  For example using OIDC:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "OpenIdConnect";

            }).AddCookie(options =>
            {
                options.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents()
                {
                   //commented out for brevity
                };
            })
            .AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
            {
                //commented out for brevity

                options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
                {
                    OnTokenResponseReceived = context =>
                    {
                        var decryptedContent = YourCryptograpy.Decrypt(context.HttpContext);
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    },
                };
            }
    );
```

Comment: I am no security expert by a long ways.  But as I understand it, a security token is meant to be used without being encrypted, only signed which proves it's authenticity. For example, see this: https://stormpath.com/blog/jwt-the-right-way

Comment: What I use is both a cookie and a jwt to get the best security from both worlds (they reference each other, so both are required to get in my security door)